# Java Recursion Pass by Reference in ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, arraylist

I am working on a problem to find which all combinations of integer in a given list can sum up to a given number.

```
public class SumProblem {

/*
 * Input 2-2-3-7
 * Output 2+2+3 and 7
 */

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  find(ArrayList<Integer> input, int requiredSum) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    find(result, requiredSum, 0, new ArrayList<>(), 0, input);
    return result;
}

public static void find(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result , int requiredSum , int currentSum,  ArrayList<Integer> partialResult, int i, ArrayList<Integer> input) {

    if (currentSum == requiredSum ) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp = (ArrayList<Integer>) partialResult.clone();
        result.add(temp);
        return;
    }

    if (i >= input.size()) {
        return;
    }
    find(result, requiredSum, currentSum , partialResult, i +1, input );
    partialResult.add(input.get(i));
    find(result, requiredSum, currentSum + input.get(i) , partialResult, i +1, input );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
    input.add(2);
    input.add(1);
    input.add(3);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  output = find(input, 3);
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

}

I have written code below.
I am facing one problem. In the below line of code, it is adding up all the numbers i traverse even if i create new ArrayList object and assign it to partialResult.

```
partialResult.add(input.get(i));
```

Could anyone suggest the solution ?

Comment: Without any code in the method, it's difficult to understand what problem you have, and what you're doing wrong to even have that problem. --- E.g. does "start afresh" mean `partialResult.clear()`? Does "transfer partialResult into results" mean `results.add(new ArrayList<>(partialResult))`? If so, what is your actual problem? If not so, then what?

Comment: @Andreas, I have added a sample piece of code.

Comment: @Manish not enough code. Show the part calling your "find" method

Comment: Do you mean something like  `find (results, new ArrayList<>(), i)`   ?

Comment: I have aded full code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two recursive calls in this dynamic programming solution to the problem. One is supposed to not include the current value in the result, the other does.

You need to make a defensive copy of partialResult, otherwise both recursive calls are going to have a reference to the ***same*** list. A list is a mutable object. If both calls get a reference to the same list object, then when you add something to it *anywhere*, both of them will see the modified list.

The easiest way to make a defensive copy of a list is just to write:

```
new ArrayList<>(partialResult)
```

Here is a working version of the program:

import java.util.*;

```
public class SumProblem {
    public static List<List<Integer>> find(List<Integer> input, int requiredSum) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        find(result, requiredSum, 0, new ArrayList<>(), 0, input);
        return result;
    }

    public static void find(List<List<Integer>> result, int requiredSum, int currentSum,
            List<Integer> partialResult, int i, List<Integer> input) {
        if (currentSum == requiredSum) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(partialResult)); // add a copy of the list
            return;
        }

        if (i >= input.size()) {
            return;
        }
        // make defensive copies in the recursive calls
        find(result, requiredSum, currentSum, new ArrayList<>(partialResult), i + 1, input);
        partialResult.add(input.get(i));
        find(result, requiredSum, currentSum + input.get(i), new ArrayList<>(partialResult), i + 1, input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> input = List.of(2, 8, 2, 3, 4);
        List<List<Integer>> output = find(input, 7);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [[3, 4], [2, 2, 3]]

I've made a few other changes:

- Use `List<Integer>` and `List<List<Integer>>` as the types (code to the interface)
- Use `List.of()` to create the input list (added in Java 9)
- Don't call `toString()` on objects passed to `println` — it's unneeded

Comment: Awesome David. Thanks a lot ! U rock.